# Show multiple div after click button only if checkbox are checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to show one or two div after click a submit button, but only if first and/or second checkbox are checked. I have this code:

```js
var first = true;
$('input[type="checkbox"][name^=chk]').change(function() {
  var $target = $('#sb' + this.id.replace('chk', '')).toggle(this.checked);
  if (first) {
    $('div[id^=sb]').not($target).hide();
    first = false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
<input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="">checkme2
<div id="sb1" style="display: none;">Checkbox content one</div>
<div id="sb2" style="display: none;">Checkbox content two</div>
```

I'm not expert on JavaScript.
Is there a way to add a submit button to show the first or/and second div after click on button?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to implement onClick() event over the button with function that checks if checkbox is checked.

```
function showDiv(){
   if(document.getElementById('chk1').checked){ 
       $div1.show()
   } else {
       $div1.hide()
   }
   if(document.getElementById('chk2').checked){
       $div2.show()
   } else {
       $div2.hide()
   }
}
```

here you have working example: https://jsfiddle.net/j30reczv/24/

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code is really good. But I have this problem: since these div are contained into html form, when user click on the first button to show hidden divs, the form will be submit. Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: for example is it possible to replace button with href link?