# Show div after click on href link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I solve my first issue to show one or two div based on checkbox selection ([Show multiple div after click button only if checkbox are checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73252492/show-multiple-div-after-click-button-only-if-checkbox-are-checked) - thanks @J4k3z).

My code is:

```js
$div1 = $(".div1");
$div2 = $(".div2");

$div1.hide()
$div2.hide()

function showDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('chk1').checked) {
    $div1.show()
  } else {
    $div1.hide()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('chk2').checked) {
    $div2.show()
  } else {
    $div2.hide()
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" placeholder="Yes">
<label>Div 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" placeholder="Yes">
<label>Div 2</label>
<br />
<button onClick="showDiv()">Check!</button>
<br />
<div class="div1">Div no 1</div>
<div class="div2">Div no 2</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code run by button.
Is it possible to replace button with href link?

Comment: From a usability standpoint, why do you even want the user to click on a button, instead of just showing the div directly when the user is clicking on one of the checkboxes?

Comment: Because if user choose both checkboxes, I prefer that divs appears at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

In your HTML, you have to make a link with an id

```
<a id='link-id' href='#'>some link</a>
```

After, in jQuery there is an [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```js
$('#link-id').on('click', showDiv);
```

### Update:

Here is the runable code example

```js
$div1 = $(".div1");
$div2 = $(".div2");

$div1.hide()
$div2.hide()

function showDiv(){
    if(document.getElementById('chk1').checked){    
        $div1.show()
    } else {
        $div1.hide()
    }
    if(document.getElementById('chk2').checked){
        $div2.show()
    } else {
        $div2.hide()
    }
}

$('#link-id').on('click', showDiv)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" placeholder="Yes">
<label>Div 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" placeholder="Yes">
<label>Div 2</label>
<br />

<a href='https://google.com' id='link-id' target="_blank" >Google link. Press here</a>

<br />
<div class="div1">Div no 1</div>
<div class="div2">Div no 2</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, @Mansur. Please can you help me to update my javascript code indicated in my first message? Unfortunately I'm not expert on this, and the function have also a check to see if checkbox are selected..

Comment: @James, there was a mistake in my code, i fixed it. You can check out and run the example if that's what you thought of